# Are bytes on a TCP socket connection lost if the connection is severed before the bytes are read?

Tags: java, sockets, nio

If I have a `Selector` that's accepting `sockets` and pushing them to a queue for other threads to handle, and no threads takes a socket for, say two minutes, and the client pushes data but then times out and disconnects. When a `thread` then takes one of those now closed `sockets` and tries to read from it, will it get the data that has already been sent by the client, or will there be nothing there to read?

Comment: You can't read from a closed socket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what 'severed' means.

- If you closed the socket yourself, you will get `SocketException: socket closed` from the various `read()` methods.
- If the connection was closed normally by the peer, all the pending data will be read before end of stream is signalled.
- If the connection was abortively reset, all the pending data is lost.

Comment: OK thanks, I think the second one is what I'm seeing on my server. Can you clarify what "abortively reset" means?

Comment: There are various circumstances under which a connection is reset instead of closed nicely: process exits without closing (Windows); process closes socket while there is still unread data in the socket read buffer; host receives data for connection that is already closed at its end, ... All these cause a TCP RST to be issued.